# Overriding page replies in QWebView

Tags: c++, json, qt, qwebview

I'm attempting to intercept a page/form request within Qt's QWebView and respond in some cases with alternative content.

```
QNetworkReply* ngcBrowser::createRequest(Operation operation, const QNetworkRequest& request, QIODevice* ioDevice)
{
        view->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(this);

        QNetworkReply* response = NULL;

        if (request.url().path().endsWith("ajax")) 
        {
            response = QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(operation, request, ioDevice);

            response->write("{ success: true }");
        }
        else
        {
            response = QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(operation, request, ioDevice);
        }

        return response;
}
```

As you can see above I've overridden the QNAM createRequest method to receive all page requests and respond with a JSON object if the Url ends with a .ajax extension. However i'm finding it hard to write data back into the network stream.

Any hints or tips on how to go about this?

Cheers,
Ben

**Update:**

Hi Abhijith, 
I've attempted your solution however it fails to connect the signal to the slot.

```
QNetworkAccessManager* nam = view->page()->networkAccessManager();

bool status = QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyReceived(QNetworkReply*)));

if(!status)
{
QErrorMessage errorMessage;
errorMessage.showMessage("connect failed");
errorMessage.exec();
}
```

*Error:*

Object::connect: No such slot ngcBrowser::replyRecieved(QNetworkReply*)

**Update**:

Ok I've managed to get his working however when i attempt to write to the IODevice is fails indicating its a ReadOnly device.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So if a  url ends with .ajax , do you just want to send JSON as a reply and nothing else ? or do you want to append your JSON to the http Response ?

Comment: I wish to append the JSON to the http response. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this . This is one way.

```
connect(networkAccessManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replyReceived(QNetworkReply*)))
....

void replyReceived(QNetworkReply* reply)    // reply slot
{
    if(reply->request().url().path().endsWith("ajax"))
    {
      QByteArray array = reply->readll();/*reply is cleared after this call and will not contains anything.*/
      /*Write the JSON wherever you want to in the array*/
      reply->write(array);

    }
}
```

You Have to fine tune this depending on which signal you want to listen  to - replyfinished from QNAM or finished from QNetworkReply etc.

Comment: Hello Abhijith, Any ideas on the fact he QNetworkReply is readonly? Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: have you tried qnetworkreply->setOpenMode(QIODevice::ReadWrite) ?

Comment: i guess extending QNetworkReply is an option.That should let you modify whatever is in Qnetworkreply.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work as the setOpenMode is a protected method of QIODevice.

Comment: Since it is not private you will be able to override it when you subclass QNetworkReply , which is a subclass of QIODevice.

Comment: Ok if i call reply->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite) i can write tot he device without failure... but no content shows up when its written? Cheers for your help anyhow.

Comment: what does write() method return ? what does bytesAvailable() return ?

Comment: write returns -1 and i don't receive any error message to the console?