# Get raw packet data from Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, packet

I was searching for a method to access & tamper the raw packet data sent and received by a Qt application but could not find anything. Is there any method?
Or if not the application at least a method to access the packet data from a QWebView.

Is there any method to achieve any of the above two?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you writing a Qt application and need to access "raw data packets"? What do you mean "raw data"?

Comment: What I mean to say is, I have made a Browser using QWebView. Now whenever the QWebView downloads/uploads data from the internet I want to get access to the http packet data that was sent and received, and tamper with it. Is it possible?

Comment: ...and what about a proxy server? I explain better in a new answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry, Sam, I cannot make it work. I've been trying everything I can imagine, but nothing goes as it would have been desired.

Let's make a short list of options and what can and cannot be done:

- You can access the retrieved web page by means of obtaining the `QWebFrame` with `webView->page()->currentFrame()` and then accessing to methods like `setContents()`, `setHtml()`, `toHtml()` or `toPlainText()`. You can, by those functions, change dynamically the web page shown in the widget.
- You can access the raw response (as an array of bytes) received for each request, by means of the method `reply->readAll()` in the `replyFinished()` slot.
- It's possible to intercept the requests, by overriding the `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` method in a network access manager of your own. There you can access the URL and the headers sent in the request and change them or cancel the request.

But... you want to access to the request and replied data for **each** request.

Access to the request is easy, it's already been explained by the override to the `createRequest()` method in a custom `QNetworkAccessManager`. But let's talk about the other part:

- For what I've seen, the reply obtained from the request **is read-only** and **IT CAN'T BE CHANGED**, as it's hard-coded in the source code for `QNetworkReply`.
- You **cannot use** the `writeData()` function of `QNetworkReply`, as it is hardcoded to simply do `return -1`!!!
- You can try to subclass a `QNetworkReply` of your own and return it in the `createRequest()` method of a custom `QNetworkAccessManager`. You must override the functions `readAll()`, `bytesAvailable()`, and `abort()`. Curiously, **this method works only if the request is made to a non-HTTP destination**. I think the internals of `QNetworkAccessManager` invokes different implementations of the `QNetworkReply` depending of the protocol used (HTTP, FTP, ...). So this worked in a sense, but not in the way we want. This method can be used to return a predefined web page under certain conditions, for example.
- Considering the fact that `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` must return a `QNetworkReply` object, I cannot see any combination of subclassing that permits tampering in the replied byte array. It's really well protected and you must reimplement everything on those classes to be able to achieve your goal. Almost copy-paste the source classes of all the `QtNetwork` part and make your own implementation.

So I think that the answer would be: "*No, it seems that it cannot be done exactly as you ask; only partially*".

Sorry.

Comment: At first I thought it was a simple task. I take my words back!! Anyways, thanks a lot Felix for providing such a great support and for spending your precious time for helping me(at least it helped me get a clear understanding of how QNetworkAccessManager works)! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The proper method to tamper with data sent / received to and from a server in a network connection is by the means of `QNetworkAccessManager`.

This class lets you send a request to a server (probably with headers) and get the response (also with headers).

You can access to the data received on the corresponding `QNetworkReply` object. Also the headers of the response:

```
{
  ...
  QNetworkAccessManager *qnam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  connect(qnam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
          this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

  QNetworkRequest request;
  request.setUrl(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
  request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Foo browser");
  qnam->get(QNetworkRequest(request));
  ...
}
```

Then define the slot:

```
void MyWidget::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
  QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
  QString mime = reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
  ...
}
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QNetworkAccessManager.html) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html).

In fact, a `QWebView` has a `QNetworkAccessManager` object to execute the requests and manage the replies. You can obtain that object by means of the `QWebPage::networkAccessManager()` method. You can obtain the `QWebPage` from a `QWebView` by means of `QWebView::page()`.

---

**EDIT**

To manipulate the webpage displayed by the `QWebView`, you can directly set a new HTML contents by means of `webView->setHtml(QString html)`.

You can also access the HTML directly by methods of the `QWebFrame` class.

To obtain such object, you must do:

```
QWebFrame *wb = webView->page()->currentFrame();
```

The methods are:

- `void QWebFrame::setContent ( const QByteArray & data, const QString & mimeType = QString(), const QUrl & baseUrl = QUrl() )` for setting a new document in byte array.
- `void QWebFrame::setHtml ( const QString & html, const QUrl & baseUrl = QUrl() )` does the same, but considering the content an HTML document.
- `QString QWebFrame::toHtml () const` to get the contents as an HTML document.
- `QString QWebFrame::toPlainText () const` the same as above, as plain text.

Look at the documentation for those functions.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Finally, if you want to access or filter the requests made by the `QWebView` itself, I can see only one way: derive a class from `QNetworkAccessManager` and override the methods used to make the requests and receive the answers.

Then, make an instance of that class an set it as the QNetworkAccessManager used by the QWebView.

Let me clarify with an skeleton:

```
class MyNAM : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
  // ...

  MyNAM(QObject *parent = 0) : QNetworkAccessManager(parent) { }

  // ...

  virtual QNetworkReply * createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0) {

    // e.g. logging of the request

    // e.g. decide if the request must be made
    if (some_bool_deciding) {
      QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, req, outgoingData);
    }
    else {
      // or faked...
    }
    // etc.
  }

  // ...
};
```

In your main application, you must made:

```
// ...
MyNAM *nam = new MyNAM();
webview->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(nam);
// ...
```

From now on, all the requests will be made using that object.

This method allows a full control over the requests made by the navigator: filter and access to the request data (headers, get and post values, etc.). You could log the requests, analyze the requests and their POST/GET fields, etc.

Hope that finally helped!

Comment: So here's what I did

`QNetworkAccessManager *manager = ui->webView->page()->networkAccessManager();
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)));

void MainWindow::finished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug()<<reply->isWritable();
}`

From the above code the isWritable() returns false, so I cant edit/append on the data received. So what is the correct way to edit/append on the data received from a QNetworkReply?

Comment: The data is returned by the `reply->readAll()` inside the slot function. Look at my slot function. The `QByteArray` is the raw response (byte array). You can manipute the received `QByteArray` as you wish.

Comment: Yes I can but I want to manipulate what the QWebView displays. Even if I manipulate the reply in your slot function it does not get reflected in the QWebView.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an edit, as it would be a very large comment here!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help till now Felix, but unfortunately that doesn't help either. What you showed me was to fetch the page separately and then set it as the QWebView's html. But what I want is to access/tamper not only the HTML but also each and every HTTP request made by the QWebView itself, including all the images,css,javascript,pdf,docs,txt,etc. Absolutely anything that the QWebView requests for has to be manipulated by me and then displayed by it. So is anything like this possible? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we can override the get() method as it is not virtual. Even if we could, your code will only be able to abort the request, it wont be able to tamper the data as the QNetworkReply* received is asynchronous.

Comment: I've just reviewed a similar project made by me, and yes, you cannot override `get()`, but you **can** override `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()`, that is virtual, and is the one that makes the requests. For the responses, you just connect the `finished` signal **before** associate it to the `QWebView`. Then, it takes precedence. Look the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6060948/1056693)

Comment: Yes I had overridden `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest()` and connected to the `finished` slot. But QNetworkReply is ReadOnly so could not tamper it in the `finished` slot. Even tried subclassing QNetworkReply but still could not tamper the received data.

Comment: Have you tried `reply->setOpenMode(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` and/or `reply->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` (probably subclassing `QNetworkReply`)?

Comment: And take a look [here](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Using%20a%20Custom%20Protocol%20with%20QtWebKit), where they override `readData()` in a subclassed `QNetworkReply`. It's PyQt, but it's easy to follow.

Comment: Already tried everything you said. `reply->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)` returns true but the `reply->write(const QByteArray &data)` returns -1 i.e no data gets written. And even overriden `readData()` but it doesn't get called at all. Its such a shame that its so much difficult to do such a simple task in QT.

Comment: Yes, not an easy task, but I remember achieving something similar. Give me some time to try all this in a MWE. By tomorrow I'll tell you something about it.

Comment: No problem Felix. Thank you very much for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want Wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/ or Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/, or maybe even Charles http://www.charlesproxy.com/.

These tools don't have anything to do with Qt and can be used to inspect and intercept web traffic for all sorts of programs.

Answer (score 0):

...and what about a proxy server? A good night sleep has made me think of this possibility.

You can make one following the [loopback example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-loopback.html) and the [torrent client example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/network-torrent.html) among others. So you can capture and tamper the requests **AND** the replies.

You can configure the proxy on the client `QWebView` with `webView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setProxy()`.

This involves the construction of a process that listens to the desired port (e.g. 8080) and listen to connections on the localhost.

You must implement the protocol of a proxy by:

1. Analyzing the GET and POST operations,
2. Receive the whole request as a binary transfer,
3. Tamper with the request,
4. Send the obtained request in the connection to the destination IP,
5. Then you can capture the reply,
6. Tamper the received reply, and
7. Send the resulting response to the client webView.

Here I have no experience, but the path seems clear. It would be a lot of  coding, but I think this is really *a good option* if not *the only option*.

And more importantly: **it can be done**!

Comment: Yes of course, it can be done using a proxy server. I had thought of it before but I had also thought it can be done within the QT Application itself. But it isn't, so that leaves me with no choice but to use a proxy server. Thanks!