# How to access request body of QNetworkRequest with QHttpMultiPart?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I need to calculate a **digest** (checksum) from the **request body** (e.g. raw POST data) that is being sent via `QNetworkRequest` and include a digest signature in the **request header**.

How could I do this *before* sending the request (so the signature can be included in the header) ?

This is trivial when I'm using a byte array as the request body, but what if I have a `QHttpMultiPart` object ?

Basically something like `QHttpMultiPart.toString()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get raw packet data from Qt application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775154/get-raw-packet-data-from-qt-application)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't look like this can be done without changing Qt itself to expose this functionality. The good news is that Qt is open source, so you can certainly go down that route.

Comment: It's not about getting raw *packets* but rather the raw request body e.g. from a POST (which may be multiple network packets and will not contain any packet headers).

Comment: **It is *not* about signing the response but the request.** There is no point in the client signing the response from the server that you don't even know beforehand unless you're a clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, the only way seems to be to assemble the MIME multi-part body oneself, produce a digest of it and pass that byte data to `QNetworkAccessManager` sending method.